# thumbnailPhoto not getting in case of Global Catalog

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory, directoryservices

I have created a AD forest that search for a user across all domains in the forest using its global catalog connection string.

I am trying to get thumbnailPhoto of AD user using c# code. But I did not get thumbnailPhoto property in result object even though it exist in AD.

I had verified the thumbnailPhoto prop in AD using powershell. Also I have verified it by getting using LDAP connection string. It both case I got the byte array.

Below is the code to get user and its properties and _configuration.GlobalCatalog returns the Global catalog connections string which is in format (GC://domain-name).

```
public Task<ProfileImage> GetProfileImageByEmail(string email)
{
    var filterQuery = ("mail=" + email);
    return Task.FromResult(GetProfileImageFromAD(filterQuery));
}

private ProfileImage GetProfileImageFromAD(string filterQuery)
{
    var result = GetADUserDetails(filterQuery);

    if (result == null)
        return null;

    if (result.Properties.Contains("thumbnailPhoto"))
    {
        var imageBytes = result.Properties["thumbnailPhoto"][0] as byte[];

        if (imageBytes != null)
        {
            return new ProfileImage
            {
                Content = new MemoryStream(imageBytes),
                ContentType = "image/jpeg"
            };
        }
    }

    return null;
}

private SearchResult GetADUserDetails(string filterQuery)
{
    using (var userBinding = new DirectoryEntry(_configuration.GlobalCatalog))
    {

        using (DirectorySearcher adSearch = new DirectorySearcher(userBinding))
        {
            adSearch.ReferralChasing = ReferralChasingOption.All;
            adSearch.Filter = filterQuery;
            adSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
            adSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sn");
            adSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("givenName");
            adSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("thumbnailPhoto");

            return adSearch.FindOne();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Update: 
[image: Run LDP on AD to get user details]

Comment: Verify that thumbnailPhoto attribute is replicated between GC's (https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/musings_of_a_technical_tam/2012/02/10/identifying-attributes-that-are-members-of-the-partial-attribute-set-in-active-directory/). Also try to bind to an object directly using DirectoryEntry (GC://Object_With_ThumbnailPhoto_DN), call it's RefreshCache method and check if the attribute is returned

Comment: I have verified the [link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/musings_of_a_technical_tam/2012/02/10/identifying-attributes-that-are-members-of-the-partial-attribute-set-in-active-directory/) that you have shared Please see updated screenshot in question and I am getting the thumbnailImage byte array. But don't know what's this(GC://Object_With_ThumbnailPhoto_DN) meaning.

Comment: From your screenshot it is not clear if thumbnailPhoto is replicated between Global Catalogs.  In your code you make query to a Global Catalog, not to a domain controller by replacing LDAP: to GC: in query string. Global Catalog will return you only the limited set of attributes of an object. Let's make in another way: on a domain controller open ADSIEdit, connect to Schema Naming Context, find attribute CN=Picture,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration... and go to it's properties. Verify that isMemberOfPartialAttributeSet is set to TRUE

Comment: If the attribute is set to TRUE, in you C# application try to bind to an object directly with DirectoryEntry, instead of searching it with DirectorySearcher. E.g. var entry = new DirectoryEntry(GC://test1.rahul.com/CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=rahul,DC=com); entry.ResfreshCache(). The code will work if test1 is Global Catalog. Check if thumbnailPhoto is returned in the attributes list

Comment: Yes, I have added my attribute in Global catalog schema and now I am getting the thumbnailPhoto prop in the result object. I got my solution here. [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2b8dccfb-61e7-4c79-9f5b-0b5824e6075e/thumbnailphoto-not-getting-in-case-of-global-catalog?forum=csharpgeneral). Please add your comment so I can mark that as answer

Comment: Done. They suggested you the same thing :)

Answer (score 0):

On a domain controller open ADSIEdit, connect to Schema Naming Context, find attribute CN=Picture,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration... and go to it's properties. Verify that isMemberOfPartialAttributeSet is set to TRUE